# Make 2 arrays the same size

Tags: ruby

2 arrays of arrays:

```
a = [[1, 2], [22, 11], [18, 9]]
b = [[1, 81]]
```

What's the best way to fill out the 2nd one with [0,0] so they have the same size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b.fill(b.size..a.size - 1) { [0, 0] }
```

Comment: Good answer. I wasn't aware of the form of [Array#fill](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-fill) that takes a range as an argument. It's interesting that this works even when `b.size > a.size` (which I guess is a `Range` property). You could of course write `(b.size...a.size)`.

Answer (score 4):

Not the most efficient but pretty readable:

```
b << [0,0] until a.size == b.size
```

A little bit more efficient:

```
b.concat [[0,0]] * (a.size-b.size)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, this is more readable:

```
(a.length - b.length).times do
  b << [0, 0]
end
```

Comment: In terms of clarity, this is the best solution thus far.

Answer (score 1):

I like `fill`, but that seems to have been taken. Here's a way to return the desired array without mutating `b`. That was not asked for, but it could be useful in some applications:

```
Array.new(a.size) { |i| b[i] || [0,0] } 
  #=> [[1, 81], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

You could, of course, put `b =` in front.

Another in-place way is:

```
b.concat [[0,0]]*(a.size-b.size)
```

Hey, this is fun. Another (assuming no elements of `b` equal `nil`):

```
a.each_index { |i| b[i] ||= [0,0] }
b
```

Comment: `If b is to be modified in place, put b = in front.` - that's not in place, it's reassigning.

Answer (score 0):

I would `append` `while` the size is smaller, because I think it reads nice:

```
a = [[1, 2], [22, 11], [18, 9]]
b = [[1, 81]]

b << [0, 0] while b.size < a.size

b #=> [[1, 2], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```